# Angular2 named routes

Tags: angular, routes

I use Angular2 [Webpack Starter](https://github.com/AngularClass/angular2-webpack-starter) in [this newest version](https://github.com/AngularClass/angular2-webpack-starter/commit/a4019da853c286ecbbc3d67ad669bf92b4ccaf55) and in file ./src/app/app.routes.ts I add 'my-new-route' and i want to name it as: "my.route"

```
export const routes: RouterConfig = [
  { path: '',      component: Home },
  { path: 'home',  component: Home },
  // make sure you match the component type string to the require in asyncRoutes
  { path: 'about', component: 'About' },
  { path: 'my-new-route', component: 'Dashboard', name:"my.route" },
  { path: '**',    component: NoContent },
];
```

but there is a problem - it not working! TypeScript writes: (name) "... is not assignable to type Route[]". I check file node_modules/@angular/router/config.d.ts (which was pointed in index.d.ts) and indeed - there is no 'name' field in RouterConfig (Route class). So how to do named routes in Angular2 ?

Comment: which version you are using of angular ?

Comment: Angular2, package.json: "@angular/router": "2.0.0-rc.1" ("@angular/core": "2.0.0-rc.1")

Comment: PS: https://docs.google.com/document/d/1WLSNV3V1AKdwLwRiLuN7JqbPBKQ_S5quRlcT5LPIldw/edit# may help you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would just use [ng2-translate](https://github.com/ocombe/ng2-translate) and create the link for each language in your JSON files.

Comment: "ng2-translate expects a json for each language. if you just include the links in the json for each pipe you should be able to and put your pipe in [innerHTML]="keyfromyourlangmap|translate" it'll display the proper link. You could probably use the build in i18n pipe as well. It might be simpler to set up"

Answer (score 8):

There is a way to have named routes in new Angular2 router (which don't support it) (the main idea is from checked answer - @Michael Robison) :

in file app.routes.ts i have:

```
...
import { Url } from './common/url';

export const routes: RouterConfig = [
  { path: '',       component:  LoginForm },
  { path: Url.to('login'),  component: LoginForm },
  { path: Url.to('home'), component: Home, canActivate: [AllAuthGuard] },
  { path: Url.to('clients'), component: Cliens, canActivate: [AdminAuthGuard] },
  { path: Url.to('projects'), component: Projects, canActivate: [AdminAuthGuard] },
  ...
  { path: '**',     component: LoginForm },
];
```

And in /app/common/url.ts I have something similar to (i make below code here by hand without checking it):

```
export class Url {
    map = {
      'login': 'my-super-login',
      'home': 'my-link-home',
      'clients': 'favourite-clients',
      'projects': 'bets-projects',
    }

    public static to(routingName : string) {
        return this.map[routingName];
    }

}
```

And every where in your project in links you must also use `Url.to(...)` method (in Controllers make method `links(route)` which call Url.to, and use it in template...). 
Above Url static class is theoretical. In practice i user [polyglot.js](http://airbnb.io/polyglot.js/) small library to have support to parameters and translation for url - so my Url.to method looks something like that:

```
export class Url {
    public static to(routingName : string, values?:any) {
        return Lang.t('routing.'+routingName, values);
    }
}
```

Which use class:

```
var Polyglot = require('../../../../node_modules/node-polyglot/build/polyglot.min.js');

import { Auth } from '../';
import { en } from './en';
import { pl } from './pl';

export class Lang {
  private static instance = null;
  public polyglot:any;
  private static emergencyLang = 'en';

  constructor() {
      this.polyglot = new Polyglot();
      this.polyglot.extend({
          en,  
          pl,
      });
      if(Lang.instance) return;
      Lang.instance = this;
  }

  public static t(key:string, values?:any) {
      let self = Lang.getInstance();
      let user = Auth.user();
      let userLang = user ? user.lang : (navigator.language || navigator.userLanguage);
      let langKey = userLang + '.'+key;
      if(self.polyglot.has(langKey)) return self.polyglot.t(langKey, values);

      return self.polyglot.t(Lang.emergencyLang + '.'+key, values);
  }


  private static getInstance() {
      if(Lang.instance == null) Lang.instance = new Lang();
      return Lang.instance;
  }

}
```

For instance in ./en.ts I have:

```
export const en = {
    routing : {
        login: 'login',
        clients: 'my-clients',
        projects: 'my-projects',
        "project.pages": 'my-projects/%{project_id}/pages',
        ...
    }

    login : "Login"
    ....
}
```

And similar for other languages.

***=== EDIT: AoT support ===***

I notice that aboce solution (Url class) not cooperating with AoT. Using command `npm run build:aot` in [angular-starter](https://github.com/AngularClass/angular-starter) we will see below error:

> Error: Error encountered resolving symbol values statically. Calling
>   function 'Url', function calls are not supported. Consider replacing
>   the function or lambda with a reference to an exported function,
>   resolving symbol ROUTES in...

Because on AoT compilation app.routes.ts file is compiled using [metadata js subset](https://gist.github.com/chuckjaz/65dcc2fd5f4f5463e492ed0cb93bca60) . So below I give solution for named routes (with parameters) writen using compatibile with AoT js subset:

```
export class Url {

    public static to(routingName: string, values?: any) {

        return {
            'clients' : 'favourite-clients/' + values['client_id'],
            'projects' : 'projects/' + values['project_id'] + '/best',
            ...
        }[routingName];
    }

}
```

May be using some trick in app.routes.ts and above Url.to method it will be also posible to incorporate multilang compatibile with AoT.

Comment: You can user similar but independent solution to have named routes for API (but remember they cannot be translated - becouse from to third-part service) (i put this named routes in Url.api method)

Answer (score 1):

RC.3 is most recent Angular2 version and the new router V3-alpha7 doesn't support names. Name was removed because it didn't work out with lazy loading of routes.

Comment: this is serious problem if client of your multilanguage application want to have routing translations...

Comment: If you want to have routing translation, then every where in your application you use in links your named routes. Then in routing file only change dynamicaly path depends on language. If you don't use multilanguage, but your client like to change often routing paths its also very useful because inside your app you use NAME... so you only change app.routes.ts file, and not need to change any links in other parts of app. But this I see is imposioble now.. :(

Comment: You can create an issue for this. i18n is still work in progress. They might consider it and try to figure something out.

Comment: I make the issue but they ignore  it (and close) after 15 minutes (before I write replay) :(

https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/9550#issuecomment-228178167

Comment: You won't get "name" back, that's the reason they closed it. Name was removed for a reason. I think you would need to better explain the use case you are adressing. I don't really understand it yet but I didn't do much i18n/l10n yet.

Comment: For instance your client is BBA bank an has inner system for his workers which works on different countries. And for instance In that multilanguage system there is  page which shows operations statistics for this bank customers. And your client want to have link to this page, depends on worker language (which he choose at registration step):
EN: bba.com/dashboard/customers/123/operations/statistics,
PL: bba.com/panel/klienci/123/operacje/statystyki,
DE: bba.com/instrumententafel/kundschaft/123/betrieb/statistiken,
I meet this requirement often when I make inner sysem for global companies

Comment: @KamilKiełczewski do you have an answer for your question? I will face the same issue soon.

Comment: Yes I have, I will give it today.

Comment: Soooo ? @KamilKiełczewski

Comment: @mp3por i described in my answer above - http://stackoverflow.com/a/38266314/860099