# Angular route service with WARNING in Circular dependency

Tags: angular, typescript, routes, circular-dependency

I'm trying to write a route service in my angular 6 application which can be used by any components to search for routes in my app.

The structure looks like below

> home.component.ts
>
> route.service.ts
>
> routes.ts
>
> app.module.ts

```
//routes.ts
import { HomeComponent } from './home.component.ts'
export const routes: Routes = [
  { path: 'home', component: HomeComponent }
  { path: '', component: OtherComponent }
]

//route.service.ts
import { routes } from './routes'    
@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class RouteService {    
  ....
  getRouteByTerm(term: string) {
    this.routes.filter( r => {r.name.includes(term)});
  }
}

//home.component.ts
//Uses RouteService
import { RouteService } from './route.service'
...
constructor(public routeSearchService: RouteSearchService) {
    this.routeSearchService.getRouteByTerm('home');
} 
...
```

So since route service imports routes constant, routes imports HomeComponent, and now my HomeComponents uses route service, I'm getting a

> WARNING in Circular dependency detected

How can I fix it and is there a better way of doing it?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use approach for "named" routes. Create separate `class Url` which contains map name => path and use that Url class in your `export const routes: Routes = [...]` array, and in `RouteService.getRouteByTerm` method (and remove this.routes from RouteService class).

Here is [link with details.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38266314/860099)

Comment: I changed method to a static method, and removed  @Injectable, took service out of homecomponent constructor, so now it becomes RouterService.getRouteByTerm('') but I still see circular warning.

Comment: @user1491987 so try second approach - move that function to separate static class `RouteHelper`

Comment: I added a static class as below, but I'm still getting same warning, please let me know if I did it right: export class RouteService{
  static Search = class
  {
    static getRouteByTerm(term: string) {
      routes.filter( r=> {
        (r.name || r.path).includes(term)
      });
    }
  };
}

Comment: @user1491987 I update my answer (and change it totally)